# Variables not kept when changed in a callback

Tags: ios, objective-c++

I am making a game made in C++ which at some point wants to open make use of the camera.
To do this it interfaces with an Objective C class which presents the modal view controller:

```
UIImagePickerController* cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage, nil];
cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
cameraUI.delegate = self;

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:cameraUI animated:YES];
```

This class exposes a State variable to allow the game to watch the progress of the modal view controller.
It is initalized:

```
State = CAMERA_ACTIVITY_WORKING;
```

And updated by the UIImageControllerDelegate functions:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController*) picker
{
  State = CAMERA_ACTIVITY_CANCELED;

  [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  [picker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  State = CAMERA_ACTIVITY_IMAGECAPTURED;

  [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  [picker release];
}
```

The modal view controller opens and closes as it should and the delegates definately get called. However, when the game polls the State variable it appears to have not been updated returning CAMERA_ACTIVITY_WORKING.
I have tried making the variable volatile but this had no effect.

Can anybody help?

Edit: Full Class Source Code

.h

```
@interface Camera : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    volatile State State;
    UIImage* CapturedImage;
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController*) picker;

- (void)imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;

- (bool) IsAvailable;

- (bool) Show;

- (State) GetState;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation Camera

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(!self) return self;

    State = CAMERA_ACTIVITY_WORKING;
    CapturedImage = NULL;

    return self;
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController*) picker
{
    DEBUG_LOG("imagePickerControllerDidCancel");
    State = Poppet::ICameraActivity::CAMERA_ACTIVITY_CANCELED;
    DEBUG_LOG("State: " + STRING_CAST(State));

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    State = CAMERA_ACTIVITY_IMAGECAPTURED;

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

- (bool) IsAvailable
{
    return [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == YES;
}


- (bool) Show
{
    if(![self IsAvailable]) return false;

    State = CAMERA_ACTIVITY_WORKING;

    UIImagePickerController* cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; //Get Image From Camera
    cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage, nil];
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    cameraUI.delegate = self;

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:cameraUI animated:YES];
    return true;
}

- (State) GetState
{ return State; }

@end
```

Comment: make it strong ,and check you are not resetting them in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear method? because as the imagePicker dismiss ,these methods will be invoked automatically

Comment: I can't make State strong, its not a reference, did you mean something else? I'm not implementing viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your not using your custom `Camera` class.

You create a class

```
UIImagePickerController* cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

set the delegate and some other items and display it to the user. But this is not an instance of a `Camera` class, it's an instance of `UIImagePickerController`. I believe you want to do

```
Camera* cameraUI = [[Camera alloc] init];
```

which will give you the implementation of your custom `UIViewController` however there is a another problem. Your `Camera` class is not a sub-class of `UIImagePickerController`, it is a sub-class of `UIViewController` so it will not be a `UIImagePickerController`. I think you intended it to be

```
@interface Camera : UIImagePickerController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

On a side note, naming convention says only Class names should start with capital letters. Method names and variables should start with lower case letters.

Edit from comment:

Your `Show` method doesn't appeared to be called from anywhere, so I'm not sure how it would be used. More than that, looking at the method, I'm not sure how it would be used. The `-` at the beginning means it's an instance method which can only be called on an instance of `Camera`, but it is used to create and show an instance of `Camera` so the method requires and instance of an object to create and display a newly created instance of the object. Probably not what is intended. You could use a `+` to make it a class method and call it with `[Camera Show]`, but you wouldn't be able to access instance variables because they would not exist.

Currently, I don't see anywhere where a `Camera` is created (outside `Show`) and could become the active view controller so it looks like you are just displaying a generic `UIImagePickerController` and not your custom class.

Comment: I have amended class Camera to inherit from UIImagePickerController and void Show now uses self instead of allocating a standard UIImagePickerController which is an improvement on the code but unfortunately, the problem remains.

Comment: I found the problem.
When I was accidentally allocating my Camera class twice and checking the wrong instance.
(Similar to your answer but it was happening elsewhere in the code)